# Views combine field expose filter with multiple taxonomy terms Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I have a taxonomy with multiple term reference fields, I created a listing view and I want to add a combined field expose filter on this view with term name and term reference fields which are also taxonomies'. I have created a combined field filter it's not working with reference fields when I searched with the term name of that reference field, but its working when I searched with term id. 
Any idea how can I achieve this to search with reference fields term name via exposing filter?